# Unit testing for component methods angular 7

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular7

My Component code -

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, OnChanges, SimpleChanges,  Output } from '@angular/core';
import { CI, CiWithStatus } from '../ci-list.service';
import { ContextPanelApi } from '../../../../../../../../shared/shared-html/js/directives/oprContextPanel/oprContextPanel/oprContextPanelApi.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'opr-watchlist-cards',
  templateUrl: './watchlist-cards.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./watchlist-cards.component.scss']
})
export class WatchlistCardsComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  @Input() ciList: CiWithStatus[];
  @Input() itemWidth: number;
  @Input() itemHeight: number;
  @Input() zoomLevel: number;

  @Output() onSelectedCisChanged: EventEmitter<CI[]> = new EventEmitter<CI[]>();

  private _selectedItems: CI[] = [];

  constructor(private _oprContextPanelApiService: ContextPanelApi) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.debug('ciList', this.ciList);
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if(changes.zoomLevel) {
      this.zoomLevel = changes.zoomLevel.currentValue;
    }
  }

  onItemClick(event: MouseEvent, ci: CI) {
    if (event.ctrlKey) {
      if (this.isSelected(ci)) {
        this._selectedItems.splice(this._selectedItems.indexOf(ci), 1);
      } else {
        this._selectedItems.push(ci);
      }
    } else {
      this._selectedItems = [ci];
    }
    this.onSelectedCisChanged.emit(this._selectedItems);
  }

  onItemRightClick(event: MouseEvent, ci: CI) {
    const position = {left: event.clientX, top: event.clientY};
    const contextPanelConfig = {
      title: 'context menu dummy ' + ci.name,
      position
    };
    const contextPanelPages = [];
    this._oprContextPanelApiService.openContext(contextPanelConfig, contextPanelPages, () => {
    });
    return false; //prevent native browser context menu
  }

  isSelected(ci: CI) {
    return this._selectedItems.includes(ci);
  }
}
```

My Spec file code -

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { SimpleChange } from '@angular/core';
import { WatchlistCardsComponent } from './watchlist-cards.component';
import { AppSharedModule } from '../../../../../app-shared/src/lib/app-shared.module';
import { WatchlistCardComponent } from './watchlist-card/watchlist-card.component';
import { ContextPanelApi } from 'shared/directives/oprContextPanel/oprContextPanel/oprContextPanelApi.service';

export class MockContextPanelApi {

}

describe('WatchlistCardsComponent', () => {
  let component: WatchlistCardsComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<WatchlistCardsComponent>;
  let params;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [AppSharedModule],
      declarations: [WatchlistCardComponent, WatchlistCardsComponent],
      providers: [{ provide: ContextPanelApi, useClass: MockContextPanelApi }]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(WatchlistCardsComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    params = {
      ci: {
        global_id: "9e76bafea39c49e786360baeb2551fd7",
        icon: "/odb/icons/unix/unix_32.svg",
        id: "9e76bafea39c49e786360baeb2551fd7",
        last_changed: 1540465938749,
        long_id: "1;;9e76bafea39c49e786360baeb2551fd7",
        name: "srv0",
        status: 0,
        type: "unix",
        type_label: "Unix",
        event: "link"
      },
      event: {

      }
    };
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should call ngOnChanges', () => {
    component.zoomLevel = 3;
    component.ngOnChanges({
      zoomLevel: new SimpleChange(null, component.zoomLevel, true)
    });
    fixture.detectChanges();
  })

  it('should call the onItemClick method', async(() => {
    spyOn(component, 'onItemClick');
    component.onItemClick(params.event, params.ci);
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      expect(component.onItemClick).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  }));

  it('should call the onItemRightClick method', async(() => {
    spyOn(component, 'onItemRightClick');
    component.onItemRightClick(params.event, params.ci);
    expect(component.onItemRightClick).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }));

  it('should call the isSelected method', async(() => {
    spyOn(component, 'isSelected');
    component.isSelected(params.ci);
    expect(component.isSelected).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }));

});
```

I wanted to cover the functions, I tried doing this in spec but still it says functions not covered.

Please guide me how i can cover the functions and statement for isSelected, onItemRightClick, onItemClick  methods

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

The reason is `spyOn()`, it will replace the orginal method with a stub. Read bout it in [Jasmine Doc for spy](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies). So, when you call `component.onItemClick`. you are just calling the spy not the original function. Hence no code coverage.

**Fix:**  `spyOn(component, 'onItemClick').and.callThrough();`. This is explained in the doc as well.

However, IMO the tests you are writing is *not very useful*. For example:

```
 line 1:     component.onItemClick(params.event, params.ci);
             fixture.whenStable().then(() => {   
 line 2:    expect(component.onItemClick).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

`line 1` - You are manually calling the `onRightClick()`. Because you call the function manually,  `line 2` will always be true. However, IRL this function will be triggered on right click/click of an element in the HTML.

What you should do is obtain the component reference like (i have not tested this code, its just a reference and i assume you have an element(button) which has an `onclick`):

```
let fixture: ComponentFixture<WatchlistCardsComponent>;    
const buttonEle: HTMLElement = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('button');
spyOn(component, 'onItemClick');
button.click();
fixture.whenStable().then(() => {   
   expect(component.onItemClick).toHaveBeenCalled(); ...
```

This will create a spy on the component function(same as you did), the difference is that you are not calling `onItemClick` manually, but the buttonclick will trigger the function call automatically hence no need to call the eventHandler manually.